# C++ operator precedence (unexpected results)

Tags: c++, c++-cli

During an exercise to swap the values of two variables using VS 2010/C++, the compiler is "not" returning the expected result for the expression.

I understand a more efficient expression - XOR x and y. This exercise is an alternative approach to obtain a similar result for x and y using an Algebraic expression.

The expected result:  x = 21, y = 11
The result from the sample CPP is: x = 11, y = 11

```
// test.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

    int x = 11; 
    int y = 23;

    x = (y+x) - (y = x);
    Console::WriteLine(System::String::Format("Value of x:", x));
    Console::WriteLine(System::String::Format("Value of y:", y));

    x = 11;
    y = 23;
    x = ((y+x)*1) - (y = x);
    Console::WriteLine(System::String::Format("Value of x:", x));
    Console::WriteLine(System::String::Format("Value of y:", y));

    return 0; 
}
```

The ILDASM output is as follows:

```
.method assembly static int32  main(string[] args) cil managed
{
 // Code size       118 (0x76)
   .maxstack  2
   .locals ([0] int32 y,
            [1] int32 x,
            [2] int32 V_2)
    IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_0001:  stloc.2
    IL_0002:  ldc.i4.s   11
    IL_0004:  stloc.1
    IL_0005:  ldc.i4.s   23
    IL_0007:  stloc.0
    IL_0008:  ldloc.1
    IL_0009:  stloc.0
    IL_000a:  ldloc.0
    IL_000b:  ldloc.1
    IL_000c:  add
    IL_000d:  ldloc.0
    IL_000e:  sub
    IL_000f:  stloc.1
    IL_0010:  ldstr      "Value of x:"
    IL_0015:  ldloc.1
    IL_0016:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
    IL_001b:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string,
                                                              object)
    IL_0020:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_0025:  ldstr      "Value of y:"
    IL_002a:  ldloc.0
    IL_002b:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
    IL_0030:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string,
                                                              object)
    IL_0035:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_003a:  ldc.i4.s   11
    IL_003c:  stloc.1
    IL_003d:  ldc.i4.s   23
    IL_003f:  stloc.0
    IL_0040:  ldloc.1
    IL_0041:  stloc.0
    IL_0042:  ldloc.0
    IL_0043:  ldloc.1
    IL_0044:  add
    IL_0045:  ldloc.0
    IL_0046:  sub
    IL_0047:  stloc.1
    IL_0048:  ldstr      "Value of x:"
    IL_004d:  ldloc.1
    IL_004e:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
    IL_0053:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string,
                                                              object)
    IL_0058:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_005d:  ldstr      "Value of y:"
    IL_0062:  ldloc.0
    IL_0063:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
    IL_0068:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string,
                                                              object)
    IL_006d:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_0072:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_0073:  stloc.2
    IL_0074:  ldloc.2
    IL_0075:  ret
} // end of method 'Global Functions'::main
```

Comment: Some good reading, whether your code is logically correct or not, as it presently violates these rules fairly significantly: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

Comment: This is not an operator precedence issue. Your code is just wrong. What you're seeing here is undefined behavior. And is actually the expected result for code like this.

Comment: What is the exercise asking for?

Comment: XOR is a terrible solution to this problem. Just as efficient as `std::swap` and that works for everything.

Comment: `std::swap` is the beginning and the end of this. You reap what you sow.

Comment: Chris, the exercise started as a puzzle to swap 2 registers using the fewest steps, thus the use of XOR. 
Arguably, any other means to swap two registers would incur more overhead (and, presumably more steps). 
The exercise was then extended to an expression.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has undefined behavior.

```
x = (y+x) - (y = x);
```

The side effect of modifying `y` in the `y = x` assignment, and reading the value of `y` in `y+x` are unordered. You cannot assume that either occurs before the other. Beyond that, the standard specifically says that this causes undefined behavior.

Reference: 2011 ISO C++ standard, section 1.9 [intro.execution], paragraph 15:

> Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators
>   and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced. [...]
>   The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced
>   before the value computation of the result of the operator. If a side
>   effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either another
>   side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the
>   value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Not only that, but to the casual reader, it's quite difficult to figure out what's going on (even if this had a defined evaluation order).  Simple code is usually better than complicated code.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation and the wiki, re: Sequence Points. I now understand what is occurring with this expression. FWIW: the behavior on OpenVMS Fortran does not support (=) operators. I understood the expression was illegal but didn't know precisely why. FWIW: I considered ::swap. I was unclear about the original problem... fewest operations to swap two registers, thus the use of XOR: a=a^b; b=a^b; a=a^b;... to extend this to variables... ::swap(a,b) would certainly have been a better alternative to swap a,b... anyway, thanks all who responded...

Comment: Sorry timeout while typing response. Pls disregard prior post.Thank you for the explanation and the wiki, re: Sequence Points. I understood the expression was probably malformed and illegal, but didn't know why.
FWIW: I considered ::swap.

The original puzzle: in fewest operations - swap two registers, XOR: a=a^b; b=a^b; a=a^b;... 
Puzzle was extended to variables (and an illegal expression). The Fortran compiler did not permit the expression (y=x) in an expression.
Thanks all who responded...

Comment: @user2394721: The Fortran compiler doesn't permit it because Fortran doesn't permit it. Assignment is an expression in C, a statement in Fortran. And in C, `x = (y+x) - (y = x);` isn't *illegal* as such. Its behavior is undefined, which means that a compiler is not required to diagnose it as an error. (And I'm not sure what "wiki" you're referring to; the quotation was from the ISO C++ standard, not from a wiki.)